# How to calculate an average across columns based on values in adjacent columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an example dataset attached. My actual dataset is much larger. The "yr" columns are split between "cd" and "qty" and go from yr 10 to yr 1. Not every row contains a full set of data, some contain zeros.
Example data:

| Sales | yr10cd | yr10qty | yr9cd | yr9qty | yr8cd | yr8qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | A | 45 | A | 47 | A | 49 |
| 56 | T | 58 | A | 52 | 0 | 0 |
| 78 | A | 75 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I want to be able to take an average of the qty columns (yr10qty, yr9qty, yr8qty, etc.) but only if the associated indicator (yr10cd, yr9cd, yr8cd, etc. ) in the adjacent column is an "A" value. if the associated indicator is 0 or any other value like "T", I do not want to include it in my average calculation.

I have tried using a function that utilizes if statements to append values to a list and then average if non zero. Then, using df.apply to apply that function to each row in the df. Unfortunately, I keep getting 0 for all my averages, which is not expected.

Here is the expected output. It is an added column to my df that contains the average for that row.
Expected output:

| Sales | yr10cd | yr10qty | yr9cd | yr9qty | yr8cd | yr8qty | average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | A | 45 | A | 47 | A | 49 | 47 |
| 56 | T | 58 | A | 52 | 0 | 0 | 52 |
| 78 | A | 75 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 75 |

I have tried searching stack overflow for sometime now and none of the solutions I have come across have worked for my specific scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some situations where the structure of the columns can be unknown it can be useful to expand out into a MultiIndex to perform operations which allows us to take advantage of pandas indexing to ensure data integrity during our computation.

Assuming a structure of `yr[num]cd` paired with `yr[num]qty` we can isolate those columns and create a multi-index such that the [num] values are in their own level.

```python
v = df.filter(regex='^yr\d+(cd|qty)$')
v.columns = (
    v.columns
    .str.replace(r'yr(\d+)(cd|qty)', r'\2_\1', regex=True)
    .str.split('_', expand=True)
)
```

Here I've isolated the interesting columns into the variable `v` and restructured the columns so that the `cd` and `qty` values are in level 0 and the numbers are in level 1 through the use of [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and [split](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html).

V looks like:

```
  cd qty cd qty cd qty
  10  10  9   9  8   8
0  A  45  A  47  A  49
1  T  58  A  52  0   0
2  A  75  0   0  0   0
```

Note there are many ways to restructure the columns into a MultiIndex. Here's another example for reference:

```python
v.columns = (
    v.columns
    .str.split(r'(\d+)', regex=True, expand=True)
    .droplevel(0)
    .swaplevel(0, 1)
)
```

Depending on the column name format different approaches may be better at restructuring.

---

The primary benefit of a MultiIndex with this level order is that we can very easily get access to all `cd` columns and `qty` columns by accessing them `v['cd']` and `v['qty]`.

`v['qty']` for reference:

```
   10   9   8
0  45  47  49
1  58  52   0
2  75   0   0
```

The great thing about this is that regardless of column order, we can reliably align computations between 10, 9 and 8.

This allows us to filter out [where](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) is [equal to](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) 'A' `v['qty'].where(v['cd'].eq('A'))`:

```
     10     9     8
0  45.0  47.0  49.0
1   NaN  52.0   NaN
2  75.0   NaN   NaN
```

Then take the [mean](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) across rows `v['qty'].where(v['cd'].eq('A')).mean(axis='columns')`:

```
0    47.0
1    52.0
2    75.0
dtype: float64
```

This has the same index as `df` so we can very simply assign the values back

```python
df['Average'] = v['qty'].where(v['cd'].eq('A')).mean(axis='columns')
```

`df` with the new column:

```
   Sales yr8cd yr9cd yr10cd  yr10qty  yr9qty  yr8qty  Average
0     42     A     A      A       45      47      49     47.0
1     56     0     A      T       58      52       0     52.0
2     78     0     0      A       75       0       0     75.0
```

---

Again something really great about this approach is that our initial data column order does not matter.

Imagine a situation where our `cd` columns are grouped with numbers in ascending order and our `qty` columns are grouped with numbers in descending order.

| Sales | yr8cd | yr9cd | yr10cd | yr10qty | yr9qty | yr8qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | A | A | A | 45 | 47 | 49 |
| 56 | 0 | A | T | 58 | 52 | 0 |
| 78 | 0 | 0 | A | 75 | 0 | 0 |

Or, perhaps more realistically, imagine a scenario where someone accidentally dragged one of the columns out of order. The approach outlined here will still result in the correct average values because the calculation and value filtering is aligning based on the numerical values and not their relative position within the DataFrame.

```
0    47.0
1    52.0
2    75.0
dtype: float64
```

So, while this is likely not the fastest solution or the most memory efficient, it *is* fairly performant while not sacrificing any alignment integrity checks that indexing can provide.

---

Complete working example with version number

```python
import pandas as pd  # v2.1.2

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Sales': [42, 56, 78],
    'yr10cd': ['A', 'T', 'A'],
    'yr10qty': [45, 58, 75],
    'yr9cd': ['A', 'A', '0'],
    'yr9qty': [47, 52, 0],
    'yr8cd': ['A', '0', '0'],
    'yr8qty': [49, 0, 0]
})

v = df.filter(regex='^yr\d+(cd|qty)$')
v.columns = (
    v.columns
    .str.replace(r'yr(\d+)(cd|qty)', r'\2_\1', regex=True)
    .str.split('_', expand=True)
)

df['Average'] = v['qty'].where(v['cd'].eq('A')).mean(axis='columns')

print(df)
```

Comment: Hi @Henry, thank you for your solution. I found it quite helpful and comprehensive. I have a similar issue I am facing, but I do not know if I should post another question. Let's say I want to see if two or more of the values in "v" for each row are less than 10% of the average I just calculated, would I be able to perform operations using "v" to answer that question?

Comment: Yes @Taylor3417 you could use `v` for that as well if you wanted to. Just compare `v['qty']` to `df['Average']` (maybe something like `v['qty'].lt(df['Average'] * .1, axis=0)`) and count the number of True values in each column. You might consider asking another question which would allow you to further explain what exactly you mean and give answerers a better chance to write out a solution in an answer field rather than comments.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```
d = (df.filter(like='cd', axis=1).eq('A') * df.filter(like='qty', axis=1).values)

df['average'] = d.where(d.ne(0)).mean(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   Sales yr10cd  yr10qty yr9cd  yr9qty yr8cd  yr8qty  average
0     42      A       45     A      47     A      49     47.0
1     56      T       58     A      52     0       0     52.0
2     78      A       75     0       0     0       0     75.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Take advantage of the alternate pairs `cd/qty`, [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) the non `A`, then compute the [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) :

```
tmp = df.set_index("Sales") # put aside the S

cds = tmp.iloc[:, ::2]; qty = tmp.iloc[:, 1::2]

df["average"] = (qty.mask(cds.ne("A").set_axis(qty.columns, axis=1))
                     .mean(axis=1).reset_index(drop=True))
```

Ouptut :

```
print(df)

   Sales yr10cd  yr10qty yr9cd  yr9qty yr8cd  yr8qty  average
0     42      A       45     A      47     A      49     47.0
1     56      T       58     A      52     0       0     52.0
2     78      A       75     0       0     0       0     75.0
```

Answer (score 1):

**Row-Method with for loop way:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def calculate_average(row):
    qty_values = []
    for i in range(10, 1, -1):
        cd_col = f'yr{i}cd'
        qty_col = f'yr{i}qty'
        if cd_col in row and qty_col in row and row[cd_col] == 'A':
            qty_values.append(row[qty_col])
    if qty_values:
        return sum(qty_values) / len(qty_values)
    else:
        return 0

df['average'] = df.apply(calculate_average, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Sales yr10cd  yr10qty yr9cd  yr9qty yr8cd  yr8qty  average
0     42      A       45     A      47     A      49     47.0
1     56      T       58     A      52     0       0     52.0
2     78      A       75     0       0     0       0     75.0
```

**Vectorized way:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
cd_columns = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('cd')].to_list()
qty_columns = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('qty')].to_list()

df[qty_columns] = df[qty_columns].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce') # replace non-numeric values with NaN
avg_qty = np.where(df[cd_columns] == 'A', df[qty_columns], np.nan) # average
df['average'] = np.nanmean(avg_qty, axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Sales yr10cd  yr10qty yr9cd  yr9qty yr8cd  yr8qty  average
0     42      A       45     A      47     A      49     47.0
1     56      T       58     A      52     0       0     52.0
2     78      A       75     0       0     0       0     75.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very scrappy answer that should work:

```
temp_df= df.copy()
columns = list(df.columns)
for col in columns:
    if col.endswith('cd'):
        adj_col = col.replace('cd','qty') 
        temp_df[adj_col] = np.where(temp_df[col] != 'A', None, temp_df[adj_col])
    
df['average'] = temp_df[[c for c in columns if c.endswith('qty')]].mean(axis=1,skipna = True)
```

Explanation: Create a temporary df. For each 'cd' column, if the value is not 'A', replace the value of the adjacent 'qty' column with None.
Then when we take the row-wise average of all 'qty' columns, we can skip 'qty' columns with None values.
Finally, when we take the row-wise averages, we simultaneously create a new column in the original df and assign the result of those averages.